# Is there a limit to the size of pages cloudfront will cache?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Is there a limit to the size of pages Cloudfront will cache, some of my pages don't seem to be getting cached in Cloudfront, or at least the cache is not being used.

**I ran the test requested**

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~$ curl -v -o /dev/null http://d353kg141fc5wg.cloudfront.net/artist/79239441-bfd5-4981-a70c-55c3f15c1287
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 54.230.197.199...
* Connected to d353kg141fc5wg.cloudfront.net (54.230.197.199) port 80 (#0)
> GET /artist/79239441-bfd5-4981-a70c-55c3f15c1287 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: d353kg141fc5wg.cloudfront.net
> Accept: */*
>
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:18 --:--:--     0< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Wed, 22 Apr 2015 19:31:05 GMT
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 8792444549c943de8bc09305ff25b8fc.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: j6DgVokc5CAjMTYVe4wM9v2zDxdlLaldX-oFZ7aPabQp4CroNh_bwg==
<
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:18 --:--:--     0{ [data not shown]
100 14.4M    0 14.4M    0     0   634k      0 --:--:--  0:00:23 --:--:-- 3337k
* Connection #0 to host d353kg141fc5wg.cloudfront.net left intact
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~$ curl -v -o /dev/null http://d353kg141fc5wg.cloudfront.net/artist/79239441-bfd5-4981-a70c-55c3f15c1287
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 54.230.196.189...
* Connected to d353kg141fc5wg.cloudfront.net (54.230.196.189) port 80 (#0)
> GET /artist/79239441-bfd5-4981-a70c-55c3f15c1287 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: d353kg141fc5wg.cloudfront.net
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Wed, 22 Apr 2015 19:31:05 GMT
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Age: 12
< X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 f8674897ecacd3a8677010df79a9b468.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: Wbmmg36r-AI7pqRmrzlswNZEtvDSMJX3WaKR1WK9xemj3b1Vmuf2QQ==
<
{ [data not shown]
100 14.4M    0 14.4M    0     0   9.9M      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  9.9M
* Connection #0 to host d353kg141fc5wg.cloudfront.net left intact
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~$
```

Comment: Per their [FAQ][1], the single file size limit is 20GB.  If your objects aren't being cached, it maybe because of your Cache-Control/Expires/Cookie header configuration.  Can you run **curl -v -o /dev/null d123.cloudfront.net/page** twice or use http://hurl.it/ to do the same and provide the output?


  [1]: http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/faqs/

Comment: @imperalix Ive run the test as requested

Comment: Looks like your request was cached.  The way you can tell is in your second request, there is a Hit and Age header.

Comment: @imperalix So looking at the output there was a miss first time but a hit second time, but that page should already be in the cache as ive looked it up a number of times

Comment: I forgot to mention, curl doesn't add accept encoding gzip, like browsers do by default. Can you add --compressed to your curl?

Comment: @imprelix tried that still getting hit, then looked up a new page on browser then tried cmd and got hit first time !   I think I might have found the issue I had ObjectCaching set to CustomizeHeaders but I only had Minimum TTL set to 84000 ( 1 day) not 8400000 as I intended (100 days) . Added to this I assumed that if I looked up an item in the cache that was older then its TTL then they would do a new lookup and replace the cached version with a new version so at least it would be valid for 1 day starting from then, but perhaps that is not the case ?

Comment: @imperalix sorry misspelt your name in last comment

Comment: @imperalix I think part of  the answer is that there are different caches for different locations (e.g US, Europe) and so will get a miss if looked up from different locaiton  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796060/why-doesnt-cloudfront-return-the-cached-version-of-these-identical-urls